# How to automatically disable inactive accounts when AD is not used

Tags: windows-server-2008

Need a way to automatically identify and disable accounts after 90 days of inactivity.
The environment is Windows Server 2008 and Active Directory is not used.
I find scripts to doing this when AD is used but nothing otherwise.

Comment: Do you simply mean local/builtin user accounts on the server?

Comment: how many servers?

Comment: how about looking at the profile file ntuser.dat check the date on it.  I think that may be the only way.

Comment: @tonyroth users can still authenticate (shares/etc) without touching their ntuser.dat file.

Comment: yep if they are not loggin in locally you are correct.

Comment: ah but those user will need to login locally somewhere right?

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in mechanism to do this with local accounts.

If I wanted to do something like this without using AD, I would build some kind of script to check for the user popping up in the security event log in the last 90 days.

Answer (score 2):

There is a powershell module in the technet repository for local user mgmt.  I have not worked with it, but it appears to do what you need.  It can be found here: http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Local-Account-Management-a777191b.
This snippet might get you started:

```
get-localuser mypc\greg |select name,lastlogin  

Name                LastLogin                                                
----                ---------                                                
Greg                6/13/2012 6:35:56 PM
```