# AutoDisable Domain Login --- Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, group-policy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to automatically disable inactive accounts when AD is not used](https://serverfault.com/questions/398488/how-to-automatically-disable-inactive-accounts-when-ad-is-not-used)

Is it possible to Auto-Disable Domain Login id, if user don't login in his system for 10-20 days.

is there any Group Policy for that?

What i know that, we can set Account Expiry date, Lock his account - if he login with Bad password, but is there any way to Auto-disable if user don't login for 10 days in a stretch.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/398488/how-to-automatically-disable-inactive-accounts-when-ad-is-not-used) someone else asked here, there is no built-in way. You would need to script a solution to do this task.